# Accidentaly removed u-boot from tinker board flash

Tags: ubuntu, u-boot, tinker

I'm new to this, so I tried (and of course failed) to install a normal desktop Ubuntu on the tinker board, and now I no longer have the U-boot on the flash, so I can't access it from my computer (a windows 10 laptop).
I tried to compile a new U-boot to put on an sd card with the tinker os, and then apparently I should be able to see the flash on the computer(according to the official tutorial on the wiki)
The thing is, when I do the `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- O=miniarm-rk3288 tinker-rk3288_defconfig all -j4` on Ubuntu, on a virtual machine, i get this:

[image: screenshot of error]

Is there an already compiled U-boot I can use? If not, then why doesn't this work, is it because it's a virtual machine and not an actual computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross-compiler required for building u-boot may just be missing from your Ubuntu system.
A working procedure for building u-boot from scratch would for example be:

```
sudo apt-get install wget

wget https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/archive/v2019.10.tar.gz
tar zxf v2019.10.tar.gz

wget https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz?revision=402e6a13-cb73-48dc-8218-ad75d6be0e01&la=en&hash=D665067126F18E366570F5B4FCCB3882DF2E7BF8
tar Jxf gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz

export CROSS_COMPILE=$(pwd)/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-
cd u-boot-2019.10
make ARCH=arm mrproper tinker-rk3288_defconfig -j4

ls -ail u-boot*
35288628 -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 5345352 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot
35288636 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  457282 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot.bin
35288607 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   15409 Nov 28 13:11 u-boot.cfg
35288662 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    9720 Nov 28 13:13 u-boot.cfg.configs
35288657 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   34966 Nov 28 13:13 u-boot.dtb
35288634 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  457282 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot-dtb.bin
35288658 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  457346 Nov 28 13:13 u-boot-dtb.img
35288655 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  457346 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot.img
35288625 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    1719 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot.lds
35288626 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  710194 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot.map
35288632 -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  422316 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot-nodtb.bin
35288630 -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 1267082 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot.srec
35288638 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  186079 Nov 28 13:12 u-boot.sym
```

Comment: Thanks it helped! Now, tho, after I compile the u-boot and flash it, it's still not "seen" by the tinker board, so it doesn't want to connect to my pc.

Comment: Do you have a USB-To-Serial adapter (see [here](https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/wiki/index.php/File:Tinker_uart.jpg)) ? This would probably help than to see u-boot messages at boot time.

Comment: No, I don't have one. from what I saw, there are to types of that "thing" that I was missing https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain